# Once the fava bean pods are formed, does the plant need a lot of sunshine to grow?

Tags: vegetables, plant-care, growth, sunlight, fava-beans

My fava bean plants now formed pods. It is getting around twelve hours of sunshine on the roof. I am worried that the weather is now getting too hot, in Egypt. Should I move it back to a shady balcony or does it still need a lot of sun to grow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They like full sun, but don't like temperatures much above 75 deg F. If your temperatures are regularly much higher in full sun, it might be sensible to either move them where there's some protection from midday sun, or provide some shading for them. Moving them out of the sun permanently isn't such a good idea.

It depends how long they've been growing though - they only require 80-100 days to harvesting, and this can be done when the beans in the pods are about the size of a pea, though some people prefer them larger than that.